# Is there any way to access a module's private functions in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to access some underscored functions in a submodule of `pandas` (in particular I want to reuse their date-conversion code), but they are prefixed with an underscore and as such not available to me. Is there any way to circumvent this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Methods are not really private in python.

You can still access methods prefixed with underscores but you're just not supposed to do so.

> “Private” instance variables that cannot be accessed except from inside an object don’t exist in Python. However, there is a convention that is followed by most Python code: a name prefixed with an underscore (e.g. _spam) should be treated as a non-public part of the API (whether it is a function, a method or a data member). It should be considered an implementation detail and subject to change without notice.

from [Python.org : Private Variables and Class-local References](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#tut-private)